# Allowing null in int text box with non nullable int

Tags: c#, wpf

So there are very similar questions about this, but none seem to solve what I'm trying to do, and maybe it's not possible. I have a form with a number of text boxes bound to int properties in my model. We allow the user to clear the field, and it should remain cleared. CUrrently if they do this they get a validation error that the it can't convert "". I understand why this is, however, due to the design I can't use int?, which I know would solve my problem. Is this possible to do, without having to define a string property to bind to? I'm trying not to duplicate all my int properties as string properties, but maybe that's the road I need to take.

Comment: would it be a solution to have the converter consider that "" = 0 ??

Comment: Perhaps you should look into why the validation error is firing.  It sounds as though the validation (or the conversion) can't handle the empty value - and I would guess that what it needs to do is convert `""` to `0` (or some other default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would like to do when the string is empty?
I mean do you want to have some int value in prop if textbox is empty? If yes, simply create a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that converts null value to that value and assign to Binding

Comment: Actually, when it's empty I'd like to put a sentinal value in the property, like -9999. This is due to the fact that one or more of the fields are optional, and this is our way to tell our COM clients that the field hasn't been populated.

Comment: As I said, you can write converter that converts null value to -999 and -999 to null string

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to represent an empty int. 
This is a dirty hack but if you chose a number say -999 that will never be valid you could use a custom converter to convert and convert back between "" and -999.

It will probably achieve what you want but I would not recommend it.